# Getting continuous info on the console when executing a command launched from within node

Tags: node.js

I have the following file **exec-deploy.js**

```
// exec-deploy.js
const exec = require('child_process').exec
exec("npm run deploy", (err, stdout, stderr) => console.log(stdout))
```

`npm run deploy`, when invoked from command line, prints a lot of data while it executes providing me with info about the progress of the deploy.

If I execute **exec-deploy** with `node exec-deploy` I do see all information only at the end of the execution, printed in one shot on the console.

Is it possible to get a continuous flow of info on the terminal even when I execute the npm script from within javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading of the official documentation and of this [interesting article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a) I found the solution for my problem, which consists in using `spawn` instead of `exec` specifying the following options

```
spawn('npm run deploy', null, {
    stdio: 'inherit',
    shell: true,
});
```

Comment: Good job on finding a solution to your problem! You can help the community by marking this question as solved.